# Firebase Firestore - 'Failed to get document because the client is offline'

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I'm using NextJS and trying to fetch data from firestore inside a component after I press a button.
I have described my function as this:

```js
const handleSkip = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const userDocRef = doc(db, "users", session?.id);

  try {
    const userDocs = await getDoc(userDocRef);

    await updateDoc(userDocRef, {
      city: "TK",
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

but when I do this I receive the following error inside DevTools console:

```
next-dev.js?3515:32 @firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.4.1): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times. Most recent error: FirebaseError: [code=not-found]: The project undefined does not exist or it does not contain an active Cloud Datastore or Cloud Firestore database. Please visit http://console.cloud.google.com to create a project or https://console.cloud.google.com/datastore/setup?project=undefined to add a Cloud Datastore or Cloud Firestore database. Note that Cloud Datastore or Cloud Firestore always have an associated App Engine app and this app must not be disabled.
This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.
```

and

```
FirebaseError: Failed to get document because the client is offline.
    at next (index.esm2017.js?a9d0:14370:1)
    at eval (index.esm2017.js?a9d0:13834:1)
```

Strangely, I'm also using next-auth and the firestore data fetching works perfectly fine inside the session callback functions.
Is there any fix for this? I've tried Firebase 9.4 and 9.6 both, but same result.

Answer (score 2):

If anybody else comes across this issue it drove me insane to fix. But lucky for you I went insane so you didn't have to.

Firstly console.log your config file for your firebase config. Yes check to see if you've put the right variable names to copy the data from your .env file.

This is where I went wrong I accident put

projectId: process.env.NEXT_**PUBIC**_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,

so instead of typing PUBLIC I typed PUBIC yes I know stupid mistake but there was nothing telling me I had typed the wrong name. But that's what fixed it for me and seems to be the same for the guy above too.

Comment: Thank you Sabin, you saved the day 

Answer (score 0):

For those also encountering this issue, I burned a morning looking around for solutions and ended up on [this post about writing to firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71890457/firebase-v9-adddoc-not-returning-success-or-failiure-or-writing-to-database).

I had a similar issue in my .env file and app.config.js files where I was incorrectly calling my Project ID (I omitted a space in the call). Check into that -- if you've been following other Firestore/React Native guides you likely copied the same snippet I did, got Auth to work, and then encountered the error when dealing with the DB.

Answer (score 0):

I also had an incorrect config file specifically my .env was off by some human error in two places, console logged it out and found the lines that were not coming through correctly and fixed them.