# Firebase V9 addDoc not returning success or failiure or writing to database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

Auth related functions work, but with firestore I cant get anything to happen. No errors no successes returned by try catch. I have created the firestore in the firebase console, The created accounts show successfully from auth, but I just can't get anything to happen in firestore database

```
export const myApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
// firebase.firestore().settings({ experimentalForceLongPolling: true });

export const db = getFirestore(myApp);
export const auth = getAuth(myApp);
export const logout = signOut;

// const dbInstance = collection(database, 'users');

export const addUser = async () => {
  try {
    console.log("Firing add function");
    const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "users"), {
      first: "Ada",
      last: "Lovelace",
      born: 1815,
    });
    console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef);
    // console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error("Error adding document: ", e);
  }
};
```

I only get "Firing add function" then nothing. No errors or anything.

If i remove the await and then console docRef instead of docRef.id, then I get "Document written with ID: " and a Promise in a pending state.

Edit: I tried to use getDocs

```
export const getUsers = async () => {
  console.log("Getting users")
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "users"));
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
    console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
  });
  console.log("After get users")
};
```

> @firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.6.11): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times. Most recent error: FirebaseError: [code=not-found]: The project undefined does not exist or it does not contain an active Cloud Datastore or Cloud Firestore database. Please visit http://console.cloud.google.com to create a project or https://console.cloud.google.com/datastore/setup?project=undefined to add a Cloud Datastore or Cloud Firestore database. Note that Cloud Datastore or Cloud Firestore always have an associated App Engine app and this app must not be disabled.
> This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.

But I go to my console and my Firestore is here and has one collection and one document that i made here from console

Comment: When you run this code, what is the output of the `console.log` statements?

Comment: I only get "Firing add function" then nothing. No errors or anything

Comment: If i remove the await and then console docRef instead of docRef.id, then I get "Document written with ID: " and a Promise in a pending state

Comment: What is your Firebase SDK version? Also do you get any error/warnings in browser console ?

Comment: Using firebase@9.6.11, follwing web 9 modular examples on the doc. And getting no errors.
However, when I tried getDocs the first time I curiously got a new error I will update original post with

Comment: Have you created a Cloud Firestore database from [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/firestore/) ?

Answer (score 3):

Embarrassing, I console logged my firebaseConfig object and realized my FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID was undefined, I looked into my env file and realized it was not capitalized, so my firebase requests just couldn't find my firestore.

I would have not thought to look here since my auth related functions were working perfectly, but I guess auth related functions didn't need project ID to work so I never caught the misspell